# Server thinks 2 clients with different IPs are the same 1 client (C Socket Programming)

Tags: c, sockets, server

I have a server that's supposed to allow one client at a time to connect, execute a command and then close. The server keeps an array list of "currently connected" IP addresses so it knows who to accept commands from.
The problem is that I have two clients who run on similar IP addresses being treated as if they are the same client.

Example: 
client A has IP address 255.255.255.153. I tell it to connect, everything works fine.
client B has IP address 255.255.255.156. I tell it to connect and the server says it's already connected.

Is my strcmp incorrect? Is it something else? Please help.

```
// Variable Declarations

int SIZE = 10; // Max number of agents
char *agents[SIZE], // List of current connections
     *times[SIZE]; // List of connection times
char buffer[MAXBUF];
int bytes_read = 0;
int total_bytes_read = 0;
int found = 0, // Bool flag
    i;
struct tm  ts;
struct timeval connected[SIZE],
               current,
               difference;
       time_t TIME;

// Initialize array to NULL
for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
    agents[i] =  NULL;
}

// Infinite Loop
while (true) {
    struct sockaddr_in client;
    int clientSocket;
    socklen_t clientLength = sizeof(client);
    memset(&client, 0, clientLength);
    clientSocket = accept(sd, (struct sockaddr *)&client, &clientLength);

    memset(buffer,0,MAXBUF);
    bytes_read = read(clientSocket, buffer, MAXBUF);
    if (bytes_read < 0)
        break;
    fprintf(stdout,"\nRead %d bytes: [%s]\r\n", bytes_read,buffer);

    char *connectedIP = inet_ntoa(client.sin_addr);

    // Option 1:
    if ((strcmp(buffer, "#JOIN")) == 0) { // Join list of connected agents
        found = 0;

        // Get current time for log
        TIME = time(NULL);
        ts = *localtime(&TIME);

        // Print message to log
        char buf[80];
        strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%a %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z", &ts);
        fprintf(log, "%s: Received a \"#JOIN\" action from agent \"%s\"", buf, connectedIP);
        fprintf(log, "\n\n");
        fflush(log);

        printf("\n%s Joining", connectedIP);
        fflush(stdout);
        // Handle #JOIN request appropriately
        for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
            printf("\nAgent[%d] == %s", i, agents[i]);

            if (agents[i] == NULL) {

            }
            else if (strcmp(agents[i], connectedIP) == 0){ // Agent found in list
                found = 1;

                printf("\n%s is equal to %s", agents[i], connectedIP);
                fflush(stdout);

                // Write to agent
                char response[] = "#ALREADY MEMBER";
                write (clientSocket, response, strlen(response));

                // Get time for log
                TIME = time(NULL);
                ts = *localtime(&TIME);

                // Write to log
                char buf[80];
                strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%a %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z", &ts);
                fprintf(log, "%s: Responded to agent \"%s\" with \"#ALREADY MEMBER\"", buf, connectedIP);
                fprintf(log, "\n\n");
                fflush(log);
                i = SIZE;
            }
        }
        if (found == 0) { // Save IP to list/queue
            for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
                if (agents[i] == NULL) {

                    // Save IP to array
                    agents[i] = connectedIP;

                    printf("\nagents[%d] = %s\n", i, connectedIP);
                    fflush(stdout);

                    // Save time to arrays
                    gettimeofday(&connected[i], NULL);
                    TIME = time(NULL);
                    times[i] = TIME;
                    ts = *localtime(&TIME);

                    // Write to log
                    char buf[80];
                    strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%a %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z", &ts);
                    fprintf(log, "%s: Responded to agent \"%s\" with \"#OK\"", buf, connectedIP);
                    fprintf(log, "\n\n");
                    fflush(log);

                    // Write to agent
                    char response[] = "#OK";
                    write (clientSocket, response, strlen(response));
                    i = SIZE;
                }
            }
        }
        memset(&client, 0, clientLength);
    }
```

Comment: You don't show how `agents` array is defined, AFAICS.  If you've defined it appropriately and store the IPv4 addresses as strings, `strcmp()` should be OK.  But you need to allow 16 bytes for storing each address; 3 units of '192.' and one of '192\0'.  So, a lot hinges on the code you haven't shown.  Please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  What you show is not an MCVE.

Comment: Added 'agents' declaration and yes sorry about the comment. Got fixed.

Comment: You store `agents[i] = connectedIP;`  Once again, an undeclared variable, but the chances are that you are using the same space for all the agents, so if you iterated over the connected agents, printing the names, you'd find they're all the same.  i'd expect something like a `strdup(connectedIP)` there.  But it still isn't an MCVE so it still isn't convenient for people to try and help you.

Comment: conectedIP's definition is shown `char *connectedIP = inet_ntoa(client.sin_addr);` I'll look into the strdup

Comment: You are mixing up strings and pointer to the latter.

Comment: You might like to read this: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: I would also recommend _not_ identifying your clients based on just their IP address. There might be legitimate reasons to open more than one connection from one IP, think NATs (possibly with virtual machines), testing scenarios, and whatever else your power users come up with. The IP address is also quite bad as the sole authenticator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The POSIX specification for [`inet_ntoa()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/inet_ntoa.html) includes the information:

> The `inet_ntoa()` function shall convert the Internet host address specified by in to a string in the Internet standard dot notation.
>
> The `inet_ntoa()` function need not be thread-safe.

The Linux man page for [`inet_ntoa()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/inet_ntoa.3.html) is more explicit about how it behaves and what the POSIX warning means on that platform:

> The `inet_ntoa()` function converts the Internet host address in, given in network byte order, to a string in IPv4 dotted-decimal notation. The string is returned in a statically allocated buffer, which subsequent calls will overwrite.

As I noted in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47620679/server-thinks-2-clients-with-different-ips-are-the-same-1-client-c-socket-progr#comment82199757_47620679) (yes, the first part of that comment was not accurate — it's hard reading code on the iPhone app):

> …but the chances are that you are using the same space for all the agents, so if you iterated over the connected agents, printing the names, you'd find they're all the same. I'd expect something like a `strdup(connectedIP)` there.

This means that because your code simply saves the pointer returned by `inet_ntoa()` in the `agents` array, the array always contains the last host looked up.  You must take a copy of the result from `inet_ntoa()` and save that, and manage the storage.  The simplest way is to take a copy with [`strdup()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strdup.html), but you must remember to free that when a connection closes.

Using `strdup()` or an equivalent mechanism should resolve your immediate problem.  Beware memory leakage.

Comment: I ended up doing `strdup(inet_ntoa(client.sin_addr))` and it works perfectly. Thank you so much. I thought storing the result to `connectedIP` would save the actually string, not just a pointer. Thanks again